# Internal notification message controller that works asyncrhonously

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, notifications

I would like to have a notifier in my `winform` application that notifies the user on events that happen. I would rather not use the `NotifyIcon` feature because there could be many messages and I don't want all of them to be shown on my windows. But would rather them be displayed in my own app.

I want it to show messages such as

1. Connection to the database lost;
2. No logger table found in the DB;
3. A new campaign is created;

It should queue the messages in case there are more than one message sent at a time.
I want the notification to run asynchronously so that it does not hinder running of the program. I also want to set a time-out for it so that messages disappear after being displayed for e.g. 5 seconds.

What would be the best way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it a message has these fields at least:

```
class Message
{
    public string message;
    public DateTime created;

    public Message(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
        created = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Set the properties, constructor etc. accordingly.

The message queue should be a specialization of [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Queue<Message> queue
```

At that point you'll have to reach the queue somehow. You can use a *singleton*, which I hate, or inject it as a service through inversion of control (which I like much more):

```
class CanSendMessagesToQueue
{
    private Queue<Message> queue;

    public CanSendMessagesToQueue(Queue<Message> queue)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public anotherMethod()
    {
        queue.Enqueue(new Message("Hello world!"));
    }
}
```

Then you'll need a UI control that fetches those messages from the queue, displays them and eventually deletes them when they get stale.

That UI control would poll the queue in intervals (say, once a second) to display/remove messages and so on.

Pay attention to multithreading, you'll have to `lock` the `queue` every time you change it:

```
lock(queue)
{
    // add or remove messages using Enqueue() or Dequeue()
}
```

Comment: but wouldn't this periodic check of messages become memory consuming for no reason?